# d3.js:vertical moving line's intersection point with two line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 for plotting line graphs. what i want to do is find intersection point of one vertical moving line with both line graphs.

Right now code in fiddle is able to find intersection point with only one graph.

```
rect.on('mousemove', function () {

 var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0];
d3.select(".verticalLine").attr("transform", function () {
 return "translate(" + xPos + ",0)";
});


 var pathLength = mainLine.node().getTotalLength();
  var x = xPos;
 var beginning = x,
  end = pathLength,
  target;
 while (true) {
 target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
 pos = mainLine.node().getPointAtLength(target);
 if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== x) {
     break;
 }
 if (pos.x > x) end = target;
else if (pos.x < x) beginning = target;
else break; //position found
 }
         circle.attr("opacity", 1)
          .attr("cx", x)
         .attr("cy", pos.y);


    console.log("x and y coordinate where vertical line intersects graph: " + [pos.x, pos.y]);
   console.log("data where vertical line intersects graph: " + [xScale.invert(pos.x), yScale.invert(pos.y)]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2SURM/

Comment: Given that you have the code for one line, you should be able to figure out how to do it for another.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2SURM/1/ i have done it but point on graph 2 is not exactly on the same line it is some pixels ahead of vertical line and mouse move on 2nd graph is not working while i have written code for whole rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
<div id="graph1" class="aGraph" style="position:absolute;top:300px;"></div>
```

to

`<div id="graph1" class="aGraph" style="position:absolute;top:300px; left:0; float:left;"></div>`

and now graph 2 is on the same line with graph 1. Here is fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/2SURM/2/

Here is fiddle with working mouse move on 2nd graph. I added second rect behind second graph.
http://jsfiddle.net/cuckovic/2SURM/3/

Comment: yes it solved the problem but mouse move on 2nd graph is not working.

Comment: That is because graph 2 is in different div and in different svg there it don't have rect in background.

Comment: can you please help me in combining these 2 graphs in same rectangle?

Comment: I've edited answer and now everything should be working.